# CoreNLP giving Could not find or load main class error

Tags: java, linux, stanford-nlp

Downloaded the CoreNLP from https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP. When I run

```
$ java -mx4g src.edu.stanford.nlp.parser.dvparser.CacheParseHypothese
Error: Could not find or load main class src.edu.stanford.nlp.parser.dvparser.CacheParseHypothese

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have misspelling - > `CacheParseHypothese`s  add `s` char at the end.

There is the [class CacheParseHypotheses](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/dvparser/CacheParseHypotheses.java).

Comment: same error with `$ java -mx4g edu.stanford.nlp.parser.dvparser.CacheParseHypotheses`

Comment: Did your try to add `-cp "*"` to search classes in your command?